# My size function is returning 0?

Tags: c++

header

```
#ifndef INTVECTOR_H
#define INTVECTOR_H

using namespace std;
class IntVector{
private:
    unsigned sz;
    unsigned cap;
    int *data;
public:
    IntVector();
    IntVector(unsigned size);
    IntVector(unsigned size, int value);
    unsigned size() const;
};
#endif
```

Body

```
#include "IntVector.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;



IntVector::IntVector(){
    sz = 0;
    cap = 0;
    data = NULL;
}

IntVector::IntVector(unsigned size){
    sz = size;
    cap = size;
    data = new int[sz];
    *data = 0;
}

IntVector::IntVector(unsigned size, int value){
    sz = size;
    cap = size;
    data = new int[sz];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        data[i] = value;
    }
}

unsigned IntVector::size() const{
    return sz;
}
```

When I test my functions in Main, (IntVector(6, 4);
    cout << testing.size() << endl;), my testing.size() test consistently outputs 0 when it should theoretically be 6 as I assign sz and cap in the IntVector functions.  Any ideas on why it is outputting 0?

Comment: If this is what is in `main()` : `IntVector(6, 4);`, I'd like to know where `testing` comes into the picture.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're creating a temporary which is discarded here:

```
IntVector(6, 4);
```

You want to create an object, like so:

```
IntVector testing(6, 4);
```

Then it [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce408a25e53f91f3).

Comment: I see.  I had it as IntVector testing; but I guess Visual Studio doesn't like it when you do that.

Comment: @user3314899 It's not due to Visual Studio.